# Convert Recordtype Name into a Text Literal for a Multiselect formula?

Tags: validation-rule, multi-select, include

I'm trying to write a validation rule that evaluates a record type name, against a multi-select picklist on User.  However, the INCLUDES statement only works with a text literal value.  Is there a workaround?

```
INCLUDES($User.Research_Items_Allowed__c,Research_Item__r.RecordType.Name)
```

So in the above:  The user is attempting to add a junction record to a contact that links the Contact to a Research Item.  Users should only be able to relate Research Items of certain record types (although they have access to see them all).  On the User object, we have a multi-select picklist with the names of the record types, and you choose which record types are applicable.

*For example:  Bob is supposed to be able to assign the "Analysis" recordtypes to the contact, so his user record has "Analysis" selected in the multi-select.  Sue should not be able to relate "Analysis" Research Items to a contact, so she does not have that item added to her user record.  The validation rule should throw a message if Sue tries to add an "Analysis" item to her contacts.*

thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like there is no way to convert Text into Text Literal. 
Idea link :
[INCLUDES() should accept TEXT() as well as text literals](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000gpVdAAI)